# Persistence problem using spring boot with hibernate, IllegalArgumentException: Not an entity

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, persistence

my log

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.4.4)


2021-04-15 19:59:32.923  INFO 12676 --- [  restartedMain] br.com.api.ApiApplication                : Starting ApiApplication using Java 15.0.2 on DESKTOP-TEEJGQ6 with PID 12676 (C:\Users\karpi\Desktop\api-hcf\target\classes started by karpi in C:\Users\karpi\Desktop\api-hcf)
2021-04-15 19:59:32.936  INFO 12676 --- [  restartedMain] br.com.api.ApiApplication                : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2021-04-15 19:59:33.017  INFO 12676 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2021-04-15 19:59:33.017  INFO 12676 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
2021-04-15 19:59:34.323  INFO 12676 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2021-04-15 19:59:34.340  INFO 12676 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2021-04-15 19:59:34.340  INFO 12676 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.44]
2021-04-15 19:59:34.462  INFO 12676 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2021-04-15 19:59:34.463  INFO 12676 --- [  restartedMain] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1445 ms
2021-04-15 19:59:34.690  INFO 12676 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2021-04-15 19:59:34.923  INFO 12676 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 35729
2021-04-15 19:59:34.998  INFO 12676 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2021-04-15 19:59:35.010  INFO 12676 --- [  restartedMain] br.com.api.ApiApplication                : Started ApiApplication in 2.686 seconds (JVM running for 3.449)
2021-04-15 19:59:46.003  INFO 12676 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2021-04-15 19:59:46.003  INFO 12676 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2021-04-15 19:59:46.004  INFO 12676 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 1 ms
2021-04-15 19:59:46.132  INFO 12676 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.29.Final
2021-04-15 19:59:46.137  INFO 12676 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000205: Loaded properties from resource hibernate.properties: {hibernate.format_sql=false, hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update, hibernate.c3p0.max_size=10, hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect, hibernate.c3p0.min_size=5, hibernate.connection.username=root, hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans=true, hibernate.connection.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/springboot?useTimezone=true&serverTimezone=America/Sao_Paulo, hibernate.show_sql=false, hibernate.connection.driver_class=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver, hibernate.c3p0.max_statements=30, hibernate.connection.password=****, hibernate.c3p0.timeout=3000, hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer=false}
2021-04-15 19:59:50.130  INFO 12676 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
2021-04-15 19:59:50.262  WARN 12676 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.e.j.c.i.ConnectionProviderInitiator  : HHH000022: c3p0 properties were encountered, but the c3p0 provider class was not found on the classpath; these properties are going to be ignored.
2021-04-15 19:59:50.265  WARN 12676 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.hibernate.orm.connections.pooling    : HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
2021-04-15 19:59:50.275  INFO 12676 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.hibernate.orm.connections.pooling    : HHH10001005: using driver [com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver] at URL [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/springboot?useTimezone=true&serverTimezone=America/Sao_Paulo]
2021-04-15 19:59:50.276  INFO 12676 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.hibernate.orm.connections.pooling    : HHH10001001: Connection properties: {password=****, user=root}
2021-04-15 19:59:50.276  INFO 12676 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.hibernate.orm.connections.pooling    : HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
2021-04-15 19:59:50.279  INFO 12676 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] .c.i.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl : HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
2021-04-15 19:59:50.683  INFO 12676 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
2021-04-15 19:59:51.398  INFO 12676 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.hibernate.orm.connections.access     : HHH10001501: Connection obtained from JdbcConnectionAccess [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess@2b29f169] for (non-JTA) DDL execution was not in auto-commit mode; the Connection 'local transaction' will be committed and the Connection will be set into auto-commit mode.
2021-04-15 19:59:51.441  INFO 12676 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not an entity: class br.com.api.entities.Persona
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.MetamodelImpl.entity(MetamodelImpl.java:566)
    at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.QueryStructure.from(QueryStructure.java:127)
    at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.CriteriaQueryImpl.from(CriteriaQueryImpl.java:158)
    at br.com.hcf.HCFConnection.all(HCFConnection.java:139)
    at br.com.api.controls.CharacterControl.getAll(CharacterControl.java:26)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:141)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:894)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1060)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:962)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:626)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1707)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
```

My metamodel

```
public static void getAnnotatedClasses() {
    EntityManager em = null;
    try {
        em = sessionFactory.createEntityManager();
        em.getMetamodel().getEntities().forEach(System.out::println); // Persona is here
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (em != null) {
            em.close();
        }
    }
}
```

My controller

```
package br.com.api.controls;

import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import br.com.api.entities.Persona;
import br.com.hcf.HCFConnection;
import br.com.hcf.HCFactory;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("api/v1/public")
public class CharacterControl {
    
    @GetMapping("/characters")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> getAll() {
        try {
            HCFactory.getFactory();
            HCFactory.getAnnotatedClasses();
            return ResponseEntity.ok(new HCFConnection<>(Persona.class).all());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

My entity

```
package br.com.api.entities;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Persona {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String description;
    private LocalDateTime modified;
    private String resourceURI;

    public Persona() {

    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public LocalDateTime getModified() {
        return modified;
    }

    public void setModified(LocalDateTime modified) {
        this.modified = modified;
    }

    public String getResourceURI() {
        return resourceURI;
    }

    public void setResourceURI(String resourceURI) {
        this.resourceURI = resourceURI;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Persona [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", description=" + description + ", modified=" + modified
                + ", resourceURI=" + resourceURI + "]";
    }

}
```

In the main method it works, so what's the problem with springboot, **I've looked, but nothing solves**, does anyone have any idea what may be happening, dependency, spring configuration, hibernate configuration, pom.xml configuration, project configuration, anything?

I added EntityScan but the error continued.

```
package br.com.api;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;

@SpringBootApplication
@EntityScan(basePackages = "br.com.api.entities")
public class ApiApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ApiApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

api I'm using: https://github.com/Eduardo-Karpinski/hcf

In an attempt to solve the problem, I modified my code to a model closer to what Spring wants, but the error continues.

```
package br.com.api;

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import br.com.hcf.HCFFactory;

@Configuration
@EntityScan(basePackages = "br.com.api.entities")
public class Config {
    
    @Bean
    public HCFFactory factory() {
        HCFFactory factory = HCFFactory.getInstance();
        return factory;
    }

}
```

```
package br.com.api.controls;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import br.com.api.entities.Persona;
import br.com.hcf.HCFConnection;
import br.com.hcf.HCFFactory;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("api/v1/public")
public class CharacterControl {
    
    @Autowired
    HCFFactory factory;
    
    @GetMapping("/characters")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> getAll() {
        try {
            factory.getFactory();
            factory.getAnnotatedClasses();
            return ResponseEntity.ok(new HCFConnection<>(Persona.class).all());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

During the debugging of the MetamodelImpl class I discovered that the error presented to me is impossible because my class that I want to persist is in Map "** jpaEntityTypeMap **".

Value of variables in the debug:

```
jpaEntityTypeMap ConcurrentHashMap <K, V> (id = 135)
    [0] ConcurrentHashMap $ MapEntry <K, V> (id = 252)
        key Class <T> (br.com.api.entities.Persona) (id = 156)
        value EntityTypeImpl <J> (id = 157)

cls Class <T> (br.com.api.entities.Persona) (id = 244)
```

**I'm starting to think it's a spring boot bug**

while running other tests, I realized that when running the following block in the CharacterControl class

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    HCFFactory.getInstance().getFactory();
    HCFFactory.getInstance().getAnnotatedClasses();
    new HCFConnection<>(Persona.class).all().forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

the same error is thrown because the ** jpaEntityTypeMap ** is null, but when I run on the Persona class, there is no error, what does that mean?

With this change the same mistake happened, spring does not like me.

```
package br.com.api.controls;

import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaBuilder;
import javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import br.com.api.entities.Persona;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("api/v1/public")
public class CharacterControl {
    
    @GetMapping("/characters")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> getAll() {
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        conf.setProperty("hibernate.connection.username", "root");
        conf.setProperty("hibernate.connection.password", "root");
        conf.setProperty("hibernate.connection.driver_class", "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
        conf.setProperty("hibernate.connection.url", "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/springboot?useTimezone=true&serverTimezone=America/Sao_Paulo");
        conf.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
        conf.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect");
        conf.addAnnotatedClass(Persona.class);
        SessionFactory factory = conf.buildSessionFactory();
        try (Session session = factory.openSession()){
            
            CriteriaBuilder builder = session.getCriteriaBuilder();
            CriteriaQuery<Persona> criteria = builder.createQuery(Persona.class);
            criteria.from(Persona.class);
            List<Persona> resultList = session.createQuery(criteria).getResultList();
            
            return ResponseEntity.ok(resultList);           
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

stack

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not an entity: class br.com.api.entities.Persona
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.MetamodelImpl.entity(MetamodelImpl.java:566)
    at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.QueryStructure.from(QueryStructure.java:127)
    at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.CriteriaQueryImpl.from(CriteriaQueryImpl.java:158)
    at br.com.api.controls.CharacterControl.getAll(CharacterControl.java:38)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:141)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:894)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1060)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:962)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:626)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1707)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
```

Pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.5</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>br.com</groupId>
    <artifactId>exemple</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>exemple</name>
    <description>Demo project</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Please add more info to your question like spring boot configuration, property file or any customisation you did, that would help someone to identify the issue.

Comment: If you are really using Spring Boot then you are trying very hard **not** to use Spring Boot. You should let Spring Boot configure the entity manager and manage your `HCFConnection` class (which is like a repository it looks like). The fact that you are using `static` methods everywhere means you aren't using dependency injection and thus are working around Spring / Spring Boot. Leading to these issues.

Comment: I added more information and the api I'm using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested your Controller code in a project and it works fine, I didn't include spring-boot-starter-data-jpa since you want to build the session factory your self:

````xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>test-self-configuration</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.7.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath />
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```
````

Comment: Thank you very much for the help, with your pom.xml i found out that the culprit was **spring-boot-devtools**, i don't know why it generated this error but without it it doesn't happen.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the package "br.com.api.entities" was not scanned so your entity is not known. You should add:

```
@EntityScan(basePackages = "br.com.api.entities")
```

in a configuration class so it will be recognized.

Regards.

Comment: My [API](https://github.com/Eduardo-Karpinski/hcf/blob/main/hcf/src/br/com/hcf/utils/HCFUtil.java) is responsible for loading the classes that will persist, but it seems that spring interferes with this in some way.

Answer (score 0):

While parsing your code, I noticed that you are creating your own session factory and entity manager in a static way. So I think you should do the same for entity package scan because @EntityScan will not work since you are not using spring.

You should add the entities manualy (or by scanning the package) like:

```java
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
...
conf.addAnnotatedClass(EntityClass.class)
```

Comment: I tried to do this, but the error continued, the last block added shows the code.

Comment: for that last code, you have the exception while running the application or when you call the controller? can you post the exception stack?

Comment: Added, the error happens in the EntityTypeDescriptor method, which says that the class that arrives by the parameter is not found in the jpaEntityTypeMap map, but this is a lie because it is in my debug, but apparently it is not the same, but this is impossible.

Comment: Your last code seems ok, may be there is some thing else in the project that causes this problem.

Comment: I just created another project using the
Spring Initializr, and I applied the same code but the error was the same, I think it is a spring bug.